# Angular 2 put method is not working with node js

Tags: node.js, angular

Actually i need to update to database using node js update method, but i have tried lot of ways but since its not working.

This are all i have tried..

### Angular 2

```
 private getHeaders(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }

 updateMethod(params : any,url : string){           
    //var content = new URLSearchParams();
    // let searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.url = url;
        /*  for (let param in params) {
               searchParams.set(param, params[param]);
        }*/          
        /*let apiHeaders = new Headers({  'Accept' : 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
          apiHeaders.append('Method', 'PUT');                           
          apiHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
          apiHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',"true");*/
          //console.log(searchParams);          
          return this.http
             .put(this.baseUrl+"api/update", JSON.stringify(params), {headers: this.getHeaders()})
             .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

### Nodejs

```
//Update Method
router.put('/api/update', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');  

    var params = {};        
    for(var keyName in req.body){
        if(keyName != "url"){
            params[keyName] = req.body[keyName];    
        }
    }   
    console.log(params);

    //Update Api Call
    request.put(
        baseUrl + req.body.url,
        { json: params },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                res.send(body);
            }else{  
                if(error == null){
                    res.send(false);    
                }else{
                    res.send(error);
                }
            }
        }
     );

});
```

I'm getting this error every time:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/api/update. Method
>   PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight
>   response.

Please give any solution..

Answer (score 1):

if you using express, i'm prefer include this lib, to enable CORS

```
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

note that: put `app.use(cors());` before declare router or in your router file

```
const cors = require('cors');


router.put('/api/update', cors(), function(req, res) {});
```

package info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: could you post your server js entry point file, ex: index.js, or app.js, etc.

Comment: and put `app.use(cors());` before define router or `router.put('/api/update', cors(), function(req, res) {});`